# Che cosa è "far trovare la letterina sotto il piatto"?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Cronaca familiare*, di Vasco Pratolini, ho letto:

> «Pensavo, non ridere, che la bambina, fra qualche anno, in un giorno come questo, mi **farà trovare la letterina sotto il piatto**!»

Questa frase viene pronunciata nel giorno di Natale dal padre di questa bambina.

Potreste spiegarmi a cosa consiste il "far trovare la letterina sotto il piatto" di cui parla questo testo? Una cerca su Google  mi ha fatto vedere che si tratta di qualcosa che si fa o si faceva a Natale, ma non capisco cos'è esattamente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Da quel che leggo si tratta di un'usanza natalizia con la quale i bambini scrivono una lettera di ringraziamento ai genitori e di buoni propositi per il nuovo anno e prima del pranzo di Natale in famiglia, la mettono sotto il piatto dei genitori o dei parenti.

Personalmente, non conoscevo questa tradizione ma dalla numerosità dei riferimenti trovati, sembra che fosse molto diffusa in Italia.

Rif:

https://books.google.it/books?id=3dJaTEOoEqcC&pg=PT25&lpg=PT25#v=onepage&q&f=false

https://it.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081105144652AAng8XI

http://www.lastampa.it/2014/12/10/cultura/opinioni/l-editoriale-dei-lettori/letterine-di-natale-fhN5lgkqVFVmS26f08n0gK/pagina.html

https://scuolainsoffitta.com/2015/11/24/festeggiare-il-natale-come-una-volta/

https://saporidelsalento.wordpress.com/2012/12/23/la-letterina-sotto-il-piatto/

Comment: Non ne ho mai scritte, ma conosco questa tradizione perché me l’hanno raccontata i miei genitori.